# Saving the image to file is getting compressed in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am new to android.I have an application which has functionality to upload image from the  gallery or take image from camera. Below I have written the code where I get the image.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode!=0){

            if(PICK_MEDIA_FROM_GALLERY == requestCode){
                if(null != data){
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    //String type = getMimeType(uri);
                    filePath =   getRealPathFromURI(uri);
                    checkFileSupport(filePath);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO == requestCode){           
                        checkFileSupport(filePath);
                    }else if(ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO == requestCode){
                        handleCameraVideo();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

This function is used to fix the write orientation for the image.

```
        public Bitmap fixOrientation(Bitmap bmp) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        if (orientation==6)
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
        else if (orientation==8)
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        else if (orientation==3)
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return bmp;
}
```

I set Image to imageview using the function

```
      private void setImagePreview(final String realPath) throws IOException {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getThumbnailBitmap(realPath, display.getWidth());

        if(null!=bitmap){

        //rotate image and save in the same filepath
            bitmap = fixOrientation(bitmap);

            FileOutputStream  fOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            RelativeLayout tempLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewLayout);
            tempLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageView previewImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previewImageView);

            previewImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

I have the an image in Camera.[image]

When I select that image from Gallery for the first time, [image]

When I try Changing the attachment and select the same picture the view appears like this
[image]

How can I solve this issue?Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you adding some view at run time?

Comment: @SweetWisher :  No, I am not adding any view at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK. Whenever I resize the image I use `BitmapFactory.Options` class. See this class.

What `Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getThumbnailBitmap(realPath, display.getWidth());` returns? A full bitmap or a Thumbnail? Thumbnail is a pretty small.

It seems that you are changing the original image instead of copy of the image. Get the file path and create your image by yourself. And, to avoid `OutOfMemoryException` use `BitmapFactory.Options` property `InSampleSize`. I am not sure about property. Just Google out and you will find.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your second image quality seems worse than the first one. You can check whether you set ImageView width and height `wrap_content`? If yes, try to set a fixed value for test. and whether the two bitmap sizes are same, width and height?